# About the layout of rwd

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with RWD CSS changes. I don’t know how to write it. My English is not good, but I try to express my problem completely.

The problem is that when the
website is in the mobile version, the line is aligned on both sides of the screen, but when it comes to the desktop device, the line must be spaced 32px from the next side.
However, the other sections of this page are required on both the mobile phone and the desktop. Keep a 32px space between the left and right, so I directly wrote padding:0px 32px in the parent layer content;

but does that mean that the gray line should be aligned with the left and right sides when the phone is on the phone?
I don't know if the CSS setting padding of the parent layer content is maintained: 0px 32px;
can we still make the hr tag display differently on mobile phones and desktops?

thanks

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 32px;
}

.content .menu {
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.content .menu .menu_item:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class='menu'>
    <li class="menu_item">about</li>
    <li class="menu_item">service</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, amet doloribus neque totam libero excepturi dolor ducimus corrupti reprehenderit! Deserunt.</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think there are a couple of things going on here. Sorry if I've got something wrong with what you were asking!

First, `padding` always works *inside* the element being defined. So, your `content` element is the top-level element here (everything else is inside it). Because the `content` element has padding of 32px left and right, that means that there are 32 pixels of space next to the edge into which no content it allowed to go (unless you start using setting `position` on child elements). So, in this case, if you  wanted your `hr` to go edge-to-edge on the screen, you would have to put it outside the `content` block (or fiddle with its width and position).

Second, if you want different effects to apply at different window sizes (e.g. on a mobile phone and on a desktop) you will need to use `@media-query`. This lets you write CSS that will over-ride your default class definitions when certain conditions are met. So, you could for example say:

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 32px
}

@media-query(max-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

What this means is that, by default, the `content` class would have padding. But if the `@media-query` condition is met (here, the window is smaller than 600px), the padding is instead set to 0.

I hope that gives you enough information to solve your problem!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your suggestion, but my website needs to maintain a 32px spacing on both the left and right sides of the mobile device and the desktop device. Only the hr label needs to maintain a 0 spacing between the mobile device and the left and right sides, but it needs to be on the desktop device. Keep the spacing of 32px, I made a rewrite, I don’t know if you have any better suggestions?


https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/XWadEZp?editors=1100

Comment: OK, so if you want your `hr` to have a different width to the parent element, you can try something like `hr { position: relative; left: -32px; width: 100%; }`. This will place the `hr` at the edge (32px to the left of its default position) and make it the same width as the parent `content` block, so it spans the whole screen,

Comment: An alternative approach is (as I said in the original answer) to place the hr outside your `content` blocks. That means ensuring that you have multiple `content` blocks, with `hr` between them.

Comment: As yet a third option: have you thought about applying a `border` to a wrapper div instead of having `hr`? Then, you'd wrap each page block in a new class that applies the border, and your styling would be all in css instead of having an explicit html element doing the job. (In this case, probably applying a `border-bottom` to the navigation block.)